# Alternative to CodeMix for vuejs for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, vue.js

I can only seem to find Codemix for vuejs for eclipse and I have to pay for that. Are the no free alternatives for editing vuejs in eclipse?

Comment: If you're a student, you may be eligible for a free license, if not, $29 should be quite cheap, but if you get into Live Chat (Help > CodeMix > Live Chat), we may be able to hook you up with a discount.

Comment: You can *try* Wild Web Developer from https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/ . It's more likely to support libraries that aren't part of the formal standard, but it might be more aimed at Angular than VueJS.

Comment: Hm yeah tried to install that but it does not recognize *.vue automatically. I guess i should just chose the javascript editor for the *.vue files